# Subclipse is no help. Has anyone gotten this error?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am trying to compare my svn branch with its working copy in `SVN`, using [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). When I launch the compare, I get this dialog box with nothing in it *(I blurred out the names of my projects to protect my company)*.

[image: thanks a lot, subclipse...]

Has anyone else come across this error that knows how to fix it? Is this a known bug?

Comment: do you get this error any other time? could be something with your working copy format if youve recently upgraded or used a different client that converted it.

Comment: @prodigitalson thanks for making me think! I tried a similar project and the same thing happened. Now I remember that these projects are checked out via command line, then imported into Eclipse. I would imaging that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a really old version?  Current version is 1.8.6, but a version like 1.6.17 would also be relatively current.  I recall this problem back in 2005 but it was fixed.  That said, I also recall the issue with the empty error dialog had something to with Eclipse whenever an exception happened inside the compare process.  So most likely we tracked down the exceptions and fixed them.  I imagine if there is some new way to get an exception that could cause the same behavior.

I would start by making sure you are current.

Comment: Hmmm... I have version 1.8.6 I think. I know it is 1.8.x, but it's not entirely clear how to determine the currently installed version (I know it's 1.8.x because that is the repository from which I installed it).